# Influence of matter of a star on masses of neutrinos

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, stars, neutrinos, dirac-equation

It is well known that if neutrinos has masses then from Dirac equation it follows that they propagate (in vacuum) as a eigenstates of mass (not as eigenstates of interaction). It's wave function is of the form

> $f_{\nu}(t,z)=e^{-iEt+i\left(E-\frac{m_i^2}{2E}\right)z}f(0)$.

In the previous formula $m_i$'s are obtained from biunitary diagonalization of matrix $m=(m_{\alpha\beta})$ which is included in the following part of Lagrangian (in SM).

> $\mathcal{L}_{\nu}=-\sum\limits_{\alpha,\beta=e,\mu,\tau}\nu_{\alpha L}^{\dagger}(x)m_{\alpha\beta}\nu_{\beta R}(x) +c.c.$

**My question is :**  The previous formula can be obtained if we assume that neutrinos propagate in vacuum. How to add influence of matter in star ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but you might want to check out the [MSW effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikheyev-Smirnov-Wolfenstein_effect)

Comment: It seems like it is what I am looking for. Now, when I have name of this effect I should be easier to found some articles. Thanks!